# How to get only one dropdown content box to be open at a time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a movie website as an assignment and the front page is a gallery of "movie cards" containing a movie poster thumnail and information about the trailer, the genre, about the film, the rating and a buy button.

I have turned the "Genre" and "About" into dropdown buttons using a code adapted from W3Schools i.e. when you click on the word "Genre" or "About", a box with text content appears.

When you click outside of the buttons "Genre" and "About", the box disappears. However, if you click both "Genre" and "About" two boxes remain and overlap with one another. How do I get only one box to appear?

In this course, I have only learnt CSS and HTML. However, the W3Schools code includes Javascript, which I have no knowledge of at all. I think the issue lies with the Javascript code but I don't know how to modify it. Would be awesome if I could have your help on it (: Thank you.

HTML Code

```
<!-- Genre -->
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">GENRE &nbsp; 
 &#9662;</button>

<div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
Drama
</div>
</div>

<!-- About -->
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="dropbtn">ABOUT &nbsp; 
&#9662;</button>

 <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
 <h1>Duration</h1>
 <p>2h 2 mins</p>
 <h1>Synopsis</h1>
 <p>Wild Tales (Spanish: Relatos salvajes) is a 2014 Argentine- 
 Spanish black comedy anthology film composed of six standalone 
 shorts, all written and directed by Damián Szifron, united by a 
 common theme of violence and vengeance.

 <br><br>
 The film is composed of six short segments: "Pasternak", "Las 
 ratas" ("The Rats"), "El más fuerte" ("The Strongest"), "Bombita" 
 ("Little Bomb"), "La propuesta" ("The Proposal"), and "Hasta que la 
  muerte nos separe" ("Till Death Do Us Part"). 
  </p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Javascript Code

```
 /* When the user clicks on the button, 
                    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown 
content */
function myFunction(a) {
    a.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content") . 
[0].classList.toggle("show");
 }

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown- 
    content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
  }
}
```

CSS Code

```
/* DROPDOWN STYLING (For "Genre" & "About") */

/* Dropdown Buttons ("Genre" & "About") */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content Formatting */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    opacity: 0.8;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
 }

.dropdown-content h1 {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: italic;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
 }

/* Genre */
#myDropdown1 {
    width: 100px;
 }

/* About */
#myDropdown2 {
    width: 300px;
 }

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
 }

.dropdown a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
 }

.show {
    display: block;
 }
```

Comment: When a user clicks on a dropdown, first check for and remove `.show` from all dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

On each function try to get an existing class for the other drop down menu, before that create a class that hides this features.

So that when you click on genre, its function assign the hidden class to about and vice versa.

I hope that was helpful.